# May I speak English in the chat related to a localized site?

Tags: discussion, chat, localization

May I speak English in the chat related to a localized site? For example, may I speak English in Stack Overflow in Russian chat? And is there any rule about it?

**P.S.** I guess I may because a chat is not a part of a particular site.

Comment: The dupe does not cover your case yet, but guess it's better to add your case in there instead of a separate discussion.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask yep